# Delete several nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an array of multiple IDs of nodes to delete. Every Cypher example I can find either deletes one node or all nodes. How would one delete nodes that match an array of IDs, in a single query?

Something like this... **(pseudocode)**:

```
MATCH (n:Node) WHERE (n.id in ['id_a', 'id_b']) DELETE n;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`IN` list operator](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/operators/#syntax-using-in-to-check-if-a-number-is-in-a-list):

If `id` is a property:

```
WITH [1,2,3,4] AS ids
MATCH (n) WHERE n.id IN ids
DETACH DELETE n;
```

If by `id` you mean the internal node id:

```
WITH [1,2,3,4] AS ids
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) IN ids
DETACH DELETE n;
```