# Neo4j cypher query for deleting all children nodes and its relationships except one child node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to delete child nodes except one child node.

when I execute this Cypher:

```
MATCH (n{name:'Java'})-[r]-(c)
return c.name
```

I am getting possible node names, but I need only longest node name and I have to delete rest of nodes and its relationships.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete several nodes in Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121728/delete-several-nodes-in-neo4j)

Comment: Please provide more details about your issue. How looks like your data model, a sample data and what you have tried so far are good ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Is there some reason you can't delete all nodes and then add back the node and properties from the one keeper?

Answer (score 1):

This query should work:

```
MATCH (n{name:'Java'})--(c)
WHERE EXISTS(c.name)
WITH c ORDER BY LENGTH(c.name) DESC
SKIP 1
DETACH DELETE c;
```

It finds all `c` nodes that have a `name` property, orders them in descending order by the length of the `name` value, skips the `c` node with the longest name, and uses `DETACH DELETE` to delete the other `c` nodes and all their relationships.